# What Lock is not reentrant i.e. blocks if acquired in the same thread without previously releasing?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

When I click `Button1` I want to `tryLock()` in the main thread and then start a background task. The background task will post `unlock()` to the main thread when it completes. If the lock is not acquired the click should do nothing and just return. I don't want to lock from within the background task's thread because initialising the task object is expensive. I want to avoid creating a task object altogether if the lock has already been acquired by a previous button click.

The same thing should happen for `Button2` and `tryLock()` should fail if `Button1`'s task has not completed. A reentrant lock won't work here since both buttons lock from the same thread.

Since the lock will only ever be acquired and released from the main thread, is the solution simply a `private boolean` class member? Does it even have to be `volatile`?

Comment: If you block the GUI thread then there is no chance of anything clicking anything.

Comment: It doesn't block. The button click starts the task and returns. The user should be able to interact with other unrelated elements on the screen except for the related buttons.

Comment: Yes, a plain non-volatile `boolean` is all you need, and should use. If you make it volatile, you can take the additional comfort of resetting it from the child thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you block the GUI thread then there is no chance of anything clicking anything. Don't use locks.

Just a plain and simple `boolean` will do the trick fine.

All you need to do is set the `boolean` to `false`, invoke the `SwingWorker` and then reset it to `true` in the `done` method. As the `done` method is invoked on the EDT and you would start the `SwingWorker` from the EDT there are no threading requirements.

In the question you say *background task will post `unlock()`*, depending on how this works you may need to use a `volatile boolean`.

If you want to detach the front-end from the back-end it might be better to use something like the [Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) pattern and have a `myControlsEnabled(boolean enabled)` method in the presenter `interface`. It's never nice for the user to have enabled GUI controls that do nothing...

Comment: I want it to be independent of the front end so I can't rely on a controls enabled/disabled state. It's in a view model class that doesn't know what the front end is. It just provides click functions to the UI developers which they must call from the UI thread.

Comment: In that case use the `AtomicBoolean`. It's overkill - you could just use `volatile` but you can make `AtomicBoolean` `final` so you can reference it from anonymous classes and the such.

Comment: In my particular case the user is able to click the "Close" button again while the screen is animating out of view even though I've told the framework to close the screen. IMO it shouldn't accept any more UI commands after that so it's not my job to disable the "Close" button.

I'd disable/enable it if it was a "Login" button.

Comment: Another problem I had with disabling the button is if I pause in the debugger, double click the button and resume, the second click event executes even if I set the button to disabled in the first click event. This won't happen during normal use, but it shows the framework's message queueing is not perfect, so I need to synchronise the clicks myself.